# Missing namespaces, LINQ works in web app but not website!

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, assemblies, namespaces

Okay guys, I have an asp.net website set up to target the 3.5 framework, using Linq to Sql.  However, the site won't build, and i get missing namespace and assembly exception whenever i try to.

Here's the catch, I have installed 3.5 SP1, and I have added the System.Core, System.Data.Linq, System.Xml.Linq, and System.Data.DataSetExtensions assemblies to the project.  What's more is, if I build the same project as a WEB APP (that compiles to a .dll), it compiles and runs just fine.  What the heck is going on?

Comment: Pls. give the exact error message.

Comment: Type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Alter the Web.config file and add the namespaces you want under the `<pages>` tag in `<system.web>`:

```
<pages>
        <namespaces>
                <add namespace="'System.Data.Linq"/>
                 // snip the rest
        </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424396/asp-net-2-0-vb-website-project-type-exception-is-not-defined).